# Is it possible to redirect a subdomain to a google drive folder with DNS records only?

Tags: web-services, redirect, dns, subdomain

I'm using [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) with a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages) to publish my website, and I'm serving all images from my public [google drive folder](http://www.komku.org/2013/12/google-drive-as-a-free-cdn.html) (because the images are licensed differently than the content served from my github repo).

Now I would like to assign a subdomain to the google drive folder: static.mydomain.com, but I don't have access to anything but the DNS settings for my own domain, mydomain.com (so no .htaccess or anything).

Is it possible to redirect the subdomain `static.mydomain.com` to my google drive folder, so that: `static.mydomain.com/path/to/image.jpg` -> points to `http://googledrive.com/host/folder-id/path/to/image.jpg`?

---

*P.S.: Of course I would like to do all this without affecting the redirect that github pages requires for my custom domain. Although I don't think that will be an issue. But just as an aside.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no longer possible to do that; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636286/using-a-custom-domain-for-google-drive-public-folder-website.

Comment: And would I need to worry about `http` vs `https` protocols, or people typing `mydomain.com` vs `www.mydomain.com`?

Comment: Ok that's good. From what I understand choosing/redirecting between with or without www is done with an A record, so these redirects will have no effect on that right? They will just work and both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com will be accessible and able to access the static content?

Comment: Sorry for the extra questions btw.

Comment: I've tried your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work.. Any ideas?

Comment: I've setup the cname, and when I try to access a file I've put in the public google drive folder through static.mysite.com/nameofthefile.ext, it times out (and cannot connect to the server). It does work for my github page, which uses `www` instead of `static` for the cname record. Also I can access the file through the default google drive url, so it is available online, and must be going wrong at the redirect..

Comment: I understand, and I have done that. I'll double check everything, and I'll upload an image of my settings if it's still going wrong.

Comment: Ah ok, so this blog post: http://www.komku.org/2013/12/google-drive-as-a-free-cdn.html is wrong. If I understand correctly it is no longer possible to use google drive as a cdn AND redirect it from a custom subdomain?

Comment: yep, I even tried it on my own domain, google seem to be detecting it and redirecting you to google homepage, or to a 404 page: I managed to get drive.mydomain.com/drive to go to the googledrive, but a public shared folder at googledrive.com/host/abcdef/test got a 404 when accessed through drive.mydomain.com/drive/host/abcdef/test :( then I found the other post. though it looks like they are using a url redirect, rather than a cname record (even though its through their fns settings)

Comment: The link to the SO article in the answer no longer exists.